# Python: Getting values of one column based on another column name

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to read a csv file and generate a sales report. For example, I have a dataset as per below

```
Category  | State     | Sales| Profits|
Clothes   | California| 2389 | 608
Stationery| Georgia   | 687  | 54
Gadgets   | Washington| 324  | 90
```

How can I get the sum of the profit based on the state and category without using pandas? Meaning I need to sum the values of "Sales" and "Profit" when category is "Clothes".

I am using the code below currently, which requires a lot manual effort.

```
with open(path,"r") as store_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(superstore_file)
    
    total_sales_clothes = 0
    total_sales_stationery = 0
    total_sales_gadgets = 0
    
    for row in reader:
        category = row.get("Category")
        if category=="Clothes":
            sales_clothes = float(row.get("Sales"))
            total_sales_clothes += sales_clothes
        elif category=="Stationery":
            sales_stationery = float(row.get("Sales"))
            total_sales_stationery += sales_stationery
        elif category=="Gadgets":
            sales_office_gadgets = float(row.get("Sales"))
            total_sales_gadgets += sales_gadgets 
    print("Total Sales for Clothes is: {0}".format(total_sales_clothes))
    print("Total Sales for Stationery is {0}".format(total_sales_stationery))
    print("Total Sales for Gadgets is {0}".format(total_sales_gadgets))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python dict. This way, you don't have to hardcode the categories
The python dictionary is a key-value data structure which is extremely useful.
In your case, key would be the categories and value would be the total sales.
Eg.

> { "Clothes" : 2389, "Stationery" : 0, "Gadgets" : 0, }

Edit : Note that you should check if the category exists. If it does, just add the sales value, else just assign the value.

```
with open(path,"r") as store_file:

reader = csv.DictReader(superstore_file)

total_sales = {}

for row in reader:
    category = row.get("Category")
    if category in total_sales:
        total_sales[category] += float(row.get(category))
    else:
        total_sales[category] = float(row.get(category))

print("Total Sales for Clothes is: {0}".format(total_sales['Clothes']))
```

If you want to traverse through the dict and print sales for all the categories use

```
for key in total_sales:
    print("Total Sales for " + key + " is : " + total_sales[key])
```

And, though you mentioned you don't want to use Pandas, I would suggest you to check its usage if you are going to work in these types of CSV Dataset for long period. Once you start, you ll find how easy it makes your job. You will save more time than what you spend learning Pandas.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I have tried the code but an error message "
builtins.KeyError: 'Furniture'" pops up. 'Furniture' is one of the category in the file. May I know how can I resolve this?

Comment: I am sorry, my bad. You should check if a given key exists in the dict before first time usage. I have edited the answer. It should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Now it extract all the values matching the category, how can I have a sum of all the values? I tried using sum () but it says "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'".

Comment: Actually total_sales[category] += row.get("Sales") already sums the sales.It takes the first sum and then adds to it the new value of sales. Can you check? Just printing the total_sales[category] should print the total sum of sales for that category

Comment: Oh my I'm not sure what went wrong, it does not sum up the values but shows a whole long list of the values in the 'sales' column..

Comment: Oh thats because the values are in string format. Can you try wrapping it with float() ? The + operator just concatenates the strings. Wrapping with float(row.get(category)) shoud solve the issue. Also check the edit, it should be .get(category) not .get("Sales").

Comment: total_sales[category] = float(row.get(category)) prompts an error builtins.TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'